# How to determine which row in dataframe has most even and highest distribution

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, distribution

I would like to sort a pandas dataframe by the rows which have the most even distribution but also high values. For example:

```
Row  Attribute1  Attribute2 Attribute3
a        1           1          108
b        10          2          145
c        50          60         55
d        100         90         120
e        20          25         23
f        1000        30         0
```

Rows d and c should rank the highest, ideally d followed by c.

I considered using standard deviation to identify the most even distribution and then mean to get the highest average values but I'm unsure as to how I can combine these together.

Comment: `highest distribution` - you are using highest average for this? Ultimately you probably will have to decide which is more important. The series with the highest values won't necessarily be the one with the evenest distribution.

Comment: You'll need to define some function that allows you weight std deviation relative to the mean that way you can have a single number to characterize each row. But that's a totally arbitrary function so I don't know that anyone here can give you a real answer... An actual statistical property, the [Coefficient of Variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation) could work to tell you how dispersed the row is relative to the mean, but it doesn't give you exactly the sorting you want.

Comment: `I'm unsure as to how I can combine these together` - Are you unsure how sorting works? Are you unsure how to *get* the mean or standard deviation? Are you unsure which statistic is more important for sorting?

Comment: @ALollz The coefficient of variation gives me something to work with but doesn't quite capture a case, say, where Attribute1/2/3 are 1, 1, and 1.01, respectively. In this case, it will generate the highest coefficient but has a very low mean. I guess that is what you meant by your last comment. I will try playing around with assigning weights.

wwii, sorry I should have been more clear. I'm unsure as to how to use mean or standard deviation, or where to place the emphasis, to get the result I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the perception of "even distribution" you mention seems to be quite subjective, here is an instuction to implement the coefficient of variation mentionned by @ALollz.

```py
df.std(axis=1) / df.mean(axis=1)

Row 0
a   1.6848130582715446
b   1.535375387727906
c   0.09090909090909091
d   0.14782502241793033
e   0.11102697698927574
f   1.6569547684031352
```

This metrics is the percentage of the mean represented by the standard deviation. If you have a row mean of 10 and a standard deviation of 1, the ratio will be 10% or 0.1

In this example, the row that could be considered most 'evenly distributed' is the row c: its mean is 55 and its standard deviation is 5. Therefore the ratio is about 9%.

This way, you can have a decent overview of the homogeneity of the distribution.

If you want the ranking, you can apply `.sort_values`:

```py
(df.std(axis=1) / df.mean(axis=1)).sort_values()
Row 0
c   0.09090909090909091
e   0.11102697698927574
d   0.14782502241793033
b   1.535375387727906
f   1.6569547684031352
a   1.6848130582715446
```

My last words would be to not be fooled by our brain's perception: it can be easily tricked by statistics.

Now if you want to improve results of higher values, you can divide this coefficient by the mean: the higher the mean, the lower the coefficient.

```py
(df.std(axis=1) / df.mean(axis=1)**2).sort_values()

Row 0
d   0.0014305647330767452
c   0.001652892561983471
f   0.004826081849717869
e   0.004898248984820989
b   0.029338383204991835
a   0.045949447043769395
```

And now we obtain the desired ranking : d first, then c, f, e, b and a

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned in a comment above, the coefficient of variation doesn't take into account the magnitude of the mean.

Comment: In that case you can weight by dividing the result by the mean. It would be std / mean**2. I will edit my answer as the results are interesting

Comment: Obviously you can tweak this adjustment to fit your needs. For example, do you think `f` and `e` should have similar scores ? The first  one has a really high mean, the latter a low std

Comment: Thanks. The squared mean got me what I needed!